# Updating Arc Toolbox paramaters with validation script

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, python-script-tool, tool-validation

I'm simply trying to disable parameter 1 if parameter 0 if entered. I modified the following, but it does not work, do I need to return anything?

```
def updateParameters(self):
  """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
  validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parmater
  has been changed."""

  if self.params[0].value == False:
      self.params[1].enabled = False
  else:
      self.params[1].enabled = True

  return [self.params[0],self.params[1]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing the opposite, right? Disabling parameter 1 if parameter 0 is empty. You don't need to return anything. I would just write this (if parameters are enabled by default):

```
def updateParameters(self, params):

    if params[0].value:
        params[1].enabled = 0

    return
```

or:

```
def updateParameters(self):

    if self.params[0].value:
        self.params[1].enabled = 0

    return
```

Comment: I see you added params argument, do I need to change anything else in the validation script?

Comment: No, this will work as well: def updateParameters(self):

    if self.params[0].value:
        self.params[1].enabled = 0

    return

Comment: Sorry no code formatting available in comments

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Very simple. Do you know if it's possible if a user selects a GDB as param1 that the user can then select 1 unique field from each feature class contained in that GDB?

Comment: @GISGe Why not edit it into your Answer where you can format it?

Comment: Done editing the answer. Yes, it is possible to access feature classes and fields based on the input GDB. But what do you mean by 'unique field'?

Comment: ignore unique field comment, so if a user selects a GDB, it will populate the toolbox with x number of featureclasses, and then the user can then select a field from each FC?

Comment: If you've defined the datatype of your parameter 0 as a gdb, you can check if this parameter is filled in, then if it's the case: create a variable like e.g. gdb = params[0].value, use it as workspace, make a list of feature classes for that gdb, apply describe on it, or whatever you want to do with Python. The toolbox will not be populated with feature classes automatically, though I don't really understand what you mean by this...

Comment: So if a user inputs a gdb, I need the user to be able to select 1 field from each fc in that respective gdb. Not sure what is the best way to do this. So if 10 fcs in 1 gdb, the user would make 10 field selections, and then run the tool.

Comment: If you have a variable number of feature classes in the gdb, this is indeed going to be difficult to implement.

Comment: yes, I was thinking of looping over the number of fcs in a gdb and creating 2 parameters for each one, the fc and a field.